# Problem with sudo apt-get update on ubuntu 16.04 lts

Tags: apt, updates, sudo

```
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/badenov/ppa/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/skunk/pepper-flash/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: http://ppa.launchpad.net/badenov/ppa/ubuntu/dists/jaunty/Release.gpg: Signature by key DCF1EB4C20F8453FBA50D7F1D9630D8970713799 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: The repository 'http://www.linuxfaq.pl/repo i386/ Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Method gave invalid 103 Redirect message
```

Comment: What did you do to get this point ?

Comment: I run sudo apt-get update

Comment: Did you install anything before now as I can see you have issues with __badenov, and pepper-flash__ ?

Comment: Can you [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/864732/edit) your question and add the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list` Might help with an answer